# Java Application to Edit the values of JVM Classpath on Websphere Admin Console

Tags: java, console, websphere, admin

So, I was thinking of making a java program that would connect to the websphere admin client and be able to edit some of the configurations in there. Basically, I would have to be able to delete all of the values on the JVM classpath. I really don't know where to start or if it's possible.

So far, I have found this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7J6S_6.2.0/com.ibm.websphere.wbpmcore.javadoc.620.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/AdminClient.html and https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rjmx_adminclient.html

Still, I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing here as I don't really have an idea. If anyone had already tried this or have knowledge on this, may you please give me leads as to what I should research on and where to begin?

Any ideas or suggestions to where to begin would help. Thank you!

Comment: 8.5.5.3 is 4 years old, does your scenario work on a contemporary/modern service level?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am wondering where to start. I have found MBean to be the way to go, but I'm still having problems on how to use them properly. I've read some documentations regarding them, but I still can't get them to work properly. I'm working on it and hopefully, get some progress.

Comment: @covener do you know which MBean I should use so that I can edit the configuration values of my JVM on Websphere? I only have 1 server with 1 node. I've been trying to figure it out these past few days, but I'm still not able to do it. I tried reading the documentation given on the IBM website, but it's a bit incomplete. I was also not able to find some sample codes that I could study. Any help would do. Thank you!